# TS2339: Property 'start' does not exist on type 'Event"select">'

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, bulma

I using vue3 with typescript and [Bulma-calendar](https://bulma-calendar.onrender.com/)
I am using the sample code as in the home page

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      date: new Date(),
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    const calendar = bulmaCalendar.attach(this.$refs.calendarTrigger, {
      startDate: this.date,
    })[0]
    calendar.on('select', e => (this.date = e.start || null))
  },
  computed: {
    niceDate() {
      if (this.date) {
        return this.date.toLocaleDateString()
      }
    }
  }
});


// The view is like:
<div id='app'>
    Selected date: { { niceDate } }
    <button ref='calendarTrigger' type='button'>Change</button>
</div>
```

Now I got error from typescript [image: Error]

Does anyone know how to solve it? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This document needs updated..

`calendar.on("select", (event) => { console.info(calendar.startDate); });`

this one works fine

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).